# Custom subview not loading in xib

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I'm trying to create a button inside the textfield , so I created a button and call the function in xibSetup(). While running the program, the function is get called . But not loading in the App. Got stuck in it.

```
class NormalLogin: UIView {

weak var delegate:NormalLoginDelegate?
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UnderLinedTextField!
var view: UIView!
func showHideButton() {
    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.width - 70 , y: self.frame.size.height - 20 , width: 50, height: 20))
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    btn.layer.borderWidth = 5
    btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    btn.setTitle("Click Me", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.passwordField.addSubview(btn) // add to view as subview   
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
}

func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
    showHideButton() // Custom button i made
    addSubview(view)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "NormalLogin", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}
```

}

Did I do anything wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure the X and Y points you have given to button frame is correct?
because I guess it should be according to the frame of password field not self.view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's happening because you are giving wrong frame to button

try this

```
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.passwordField.frame.width - 70 , y: self.passwordField.frame.height - 20 , width: 50, height: 20))
```

Comment: passwordField: UnderLinedTextField! has no member width/height.

Comment: updated. i was just pointing out button frame should be according to  passwordField.